# Prove orthogonality in C

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ $\parallel x^2 + y^2\parallel \ =\ \parallel x\parallel^2 + \parallel y \parallel^2$ IFF $x \perp y$.

What I don't understand is why this is false for $\mathbb{C}^n$.  If I recall correctly, $\mathbb{C}^n$ is the complex number space (i.e. $x+\alpha j$).

I was able to find that in $\mathbb{C}^n$, $\parallel \alpha x^2 + \beta y^2\parallel \ =\ \parallel \alpha x\parallel^2 + \parallel \beta y \parallel^2$ IFF $x \perp y$.

What I am having a hard time understanding is why the first equation is false in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and the second one is true.

Answer (score 1):

In $\Bbb C^n$, we have
$$
\|x+y\|^2 = \langle x+y,x+y \rangle= \\
\langle x,x \rangle +
\langle x,y \rangle +
\langle y,x \rangle +
\langle y,y \rangle =\\
\|x^2\| + \langle x,y \rangle + \overline{\langle x,y \rangle} + \|y\|^2 =\\
\|x^2\| + 2 \text{Re}\{\langle x,y \rangle\} + \|y\|^2
$$
So that
$$
\|x+y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 \iff \text{Re}\{\langle x,y \rangle\} = 0
$$
For a counterexample, consider the case of $x = (1,0)$ and $y = (i,0)$.  We note that
$$
\|x+y\|^2 = \|(1+i,0)\|^2 = |1 + i|^2 = 2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: in $\mathbb{C}$ 
$$<x,y>=\overline{<y,x>}$$
$$<x,\alpha y> = \overline{\alpha}<x,y>$$

Comment: I get $\parallel \alpha x^2 + \beta y^2\parallel \ = (\alpha x,\alpha x) + (\alpha x,\beta y) + \overline{(\alpha x,\beta y)} + (\beta y,\beta y)$.  There are two different scalars in the complex conjugate.  Is there a way to pull those out?  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $\overline{<\alpha x,\beta y>}=<\beta y,\alpha x>=\beta < y,\alpha x>=\beta \overline{\alpha}< y,x> = 
\beta \overline{\alpha}\overline{< x,y>}$

Answer (score 0):

$||i^2 + 1^2 || = 0 \neq 2 = ||i^2|| + ||1^2||$